# How to set the minimum resize width/height for TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TimyMCE editor, I enabled resizing, the problem is that it doesn't allow me to resize it smaller than 100x100, how can I lift this limit?

Answer (score 1):

This is hardcoded in Editor.js. There is a workaround for this as follows:

You need to do the resizing by yourself containing this code

```
var frameid = frameid ? frameid : tinymce.activeEditor.id+'_ifr';
var currentfr=document.getElementById(frameid);
currentfr.height=10; // set height to 10px
```

Answer (score 0):

in the init method you can include this sniplet to have the editor with less than 100 points

```
setup : function(ed) { ed.onInit.add(function() { 
            document.getElementById(ed.id+'_ifr').style.height='50px'; 
            document.getElementById(ed.id+'_tbl').style.height='auto'; 
        }); },
```

Comment: based on @Thariama anwser, thanks!  I haven't tested resizing, this works for initial size.